# SQL alchemy is slow in concurrent connection

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

I'm using Sql alchemy with Sql Server as database engine. I have queries that take long time (approximately 10 second). When I send concurrent requests to database, the response time takes more (Exactly, time = execution time * requests count). I Increased the connection pool but no changes have been happend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the issue is only with threads and not concurrent processes then the
DBAPI in use would be suspect.  I don't see which driver you are using
but perhaps it is not releasing the GIL while it waits for a server
response. produce a test case that isolates it just to that driver running in two threads, and then report
it as a bug on their system.